How can I close the password window in Chrome with keyboard shortcuts on Windows?
How can I  close the password window in Chrome with keyboard shortcuts on Windows?
Example of password window in Chrome:

Escape and tab didn't work.

Simply turn off these annoying prompts using Chrome Settings page.
Steps to turn-off:

Go Password settings
Turn-Off: 'Offer to save passwords and passkeys'


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
